# How to toggle hide/show closest UL in HTML using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have been using [this](http://cssdeck.com/labs/pure-css-tree-menu-framework) example to build the tree for my object. As you can see, it bases on the model of nested `ul` which builds the tree:

```
<ul class="tree">
    <li>
        Animals
        <ul>
            <li>Birds</li>
            <li>
                Mammals
                <ul>
                    <li>Elephant</li>
                    <li>Mouse</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Reptiles</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

I've been trying to add functionality to collapse the tree. For example, if I click on `Mammals`, it hides `Elephant` and `Mouse`, only within the class 'tree'.

I tried using this:

```
$('li').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('ul').nextAll('.hidden:first').toggle();
});
```

and added hidden class as display none, however, it seems that the function is not toggled when I click on any `li`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `.closest` travels UP the DOM so will never find your child `<ul>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this,

```
$('li').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/221/)

Find the child elements by using `.find()` method.

Then use `slideToggle()` toggling with a animation effect

Note: you need to use event.stopPropagation() to prevent the event to propagate to the parent `li`s

Comment: thanks so much! This saved me a lot of time! Do you have idea on how to add some type of indication (icon) that the ul element is closed?

Comment: place + and - image icons infront of the li elements and bind click events to those images.

Comment: would you bind it to the same jquery funciton?

Comment: add the new html to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jdte0m6y/)

You just need to stop click event propagation, so it does not go through all the li items. And toggle the children of the li item you clicked:

```
$('.tree li').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).children().toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```